# Как создать канал на определённом дискорд сервере?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

**Подскажите как создать текстовый канал на определённом сервере с помощью команды на другом?**
То есть есть сервер X где вводится команда !channelcreate (имя канала) (id сервера Y) после чего на сервере Y создаётся текстовый канал.

Answer (score 0):

Что же я нашёл в себе силы прочитать доки Discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def createTxtChannel(ctx, name, count, server):
    if count.lower() != 'while':
        x = 0
        while x != int(count):
            guild = ctx.message.guild
            guild.id = server
            await guild.create_text_channel(name)
            x = x + 1

    else:
        while 1 == 1:
            guild = ctx.message.guild
            guild.id = server
            await guild.create_text_channel(name)
```